# Why does "vectorizing" this simple R loop give a different result?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vectorization

Perhaps a very dumb question.

I am trying to "vectorize" the following loop:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- round(runif(10), 2)
# [1] 0.90 0.27 0.37 0.57 0.91 0.20 0.90 0.94 0.66 0.63
sig <- sample.int(10)
# [1]  1  2  9  5  3  4  8  6  7 10
for (i in seq_along(sig)) x[i] <- x[sig[i]]
x
# [1] 0.90 0.27 0.66 0.91 0.66 0.91 0.94 0.91 0.94 0.63
```

I think it is simply `x[sig]` but the result does not match.

```
set.seed(0)
x <- round(runif(10), 2)
x[] <- x[sig]
x
# [1] 0.90 0.27 0.66 0.91 0.37 0.57 0.94 0.20 0.90 0.63
```

What's wrong?

---

**Remark**

Obviously from the output we see that the `for` loop and `x[sig]` are different. The meaning of the latter is clear: permutation, hence many people tend to believe that the loop is just doing some wrong stuff. But never be so sure; it can be some well-defined dynamic process. The purpose of this Q & A is not to judge which is correct, but to explain why they are not equivalent. Hopefully it provides a solid case study for understanding "vectorization".

Comment: In light of your "remark" you should probably change the title of your question. Your definition of "wrong" was obviously different than mine. It is true that `for`-loops may be the only way to implement some models of stochastic processes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### warm-up

As a warm-up, consider two simpler examples.

```
## example 1
x <- 1:11
for (i in 1:10) x[i] <- x[i + 1]
x
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 11

x <- 1:11
x[1:10] <- x[2:11]
x
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 11

## example 2
x <- 1:11
for (i in 1:10) x[i + 1] <- x[i]
x
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

x <- 1:11
x[2:11] <- x[1:10]
x
# [1]  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

"Vectorization" is successful in the 1st example but not the 2nd. Why?

Here is prudent analysis. "Vectorization" starts by loop unrolling, then executes several instructions in parallel. Whether a loop can be "vectorized" depends on the data dependency carried by the loop.

Unrolling the loop in example 1 gives

```
x[1]  <- x[2]
x[2]  <- x[3]
x[3]  <- x[4]
x[4]  <- x[5]
x[5]  <- x[6]
x[6]  <- x[7]
x[7]  <- x[8]
x[8]  <- x[9]
x[9]  <- x[10]
x[10] <- x[11]
```

Executing these instructions one by one and executing them simultaneously give identical result. So this loop can be "vectorized".

The loop in example 2 is

```
x[2]  <- x[1]
x[3]  <- x[2]
x[4]  <- x[3]
x[5]  <- x[4]
x[6]  <- x[5]
x[7]  <- x[6]
x[8]  <- x[7]
x[9]  <- x[8]
x[10] <- x[9]
x[11] <- x[10]
```

Unfortunately, executing these instructions one by one and executing them simultaneously would not give identical result. For example, when executing them one by one, `x[2]` is modified in the 1st instruction, then this modified value is passed to `x[3]` in the 2nd instruction. So `x[3]` would have the same value as `x[1]`. However, in parallel execution, `x[3]` equals `x[2]`. As the result, this loop can not be "vectorized".

In "vectorization" theory,

- Example 1 has a "write-after-read" dependency in data: `x[i]` is modified after it is read;
- Example 2 has a "read-after-write" dependency in data: `x[i]` is read after it is modified.

A loop with "write-after-read" data dependency can be "vectorized", while a loop with "read-after-write" data dependency can not.

---

#### in depth

Perhaps many people have been confused by now. "Vectorization" is a "parallel-processing"?

Yes. In 1960's when people wondered what kind of parallel processing computer be designed for high performance computing, Flynn classified the design ideas into 4 types. The category "SIMD" (single instruction, multiple data) is corned "vectorization", and a computer with "SIMD" cabability is called a "vector processor" or "array processor".

In 1960's there were not many programming languages. People wrote assembly (then FORTRAN when a compiler was invented) to program CPU registers directly. A "SIMD" computer is able to load multiple data into a vector register with a single instruction and do the same arithmetic on those data at the same time. So data processing is indeed parallel. Consider our example 1 again. Suppose a vector register can hold two vector elements, then the loop can be executed with 5 iterations using vector processing rather than 10 iterations as in scalar processing.

```
reg <- x[2:3]  ## load vector register
x[1:2] <- reg  ## store vector register
-------------
reg <- x[4:5]  ## load vector register
x[3:4] <- reg  ## store vector register
-------------
reg <- x[6:7]  ## load vector register
x[5:6] <- reg  ## store vector register
-------------
reg <- x[8:9]  ## load vector register
x[7:8] <- reg  ## store vector register
-------------
reg <- x[10:11] ## load vector register
x[9:10] <- reg  ## store vector register
```

Today there are many programming languages, like **R**. "Vectorization" no longer unambiguously refers to "SIMD". **R** is not a language where we can program CPU registers. The "vectorization" in R is just an analogy to "SIMD". In a previous Q & A: [Does the term "vectorization" mean different things in different contexts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51681978/4891738) I have tried to explain this. The following map illustrates how this analogy is made:

```
single (assembly) instruction    -> single R instruction
CPU vector registers             -> temporary vectors
parallel processing in registers -> C/C++/FORTRAN loops with temporary vectors
```

So, the R "vectorization" of the loop in example 1 is something like

```
## the C-level loop is implemented by function "["
tmp <- x[2:11]  ## load data into a temporary vector
x[1:10] <- tmp  ## fill temporary vector into x
```

Most of the time we just do

```
x[1:10] <- x[2:10]
```

without explicitly assigning the temporary vector to a variable. The temporary memory block created is not pointed to by any R variable, and is therefore subject to garbage collection.

---

#### a complete picture

In the above, "vectorization" is not introduced with the simplest example. Very often, "vectorization" is introduced with something like

```
a[1] <- b[1] + c[1]
a[2] <- b[2] + c[2]
a[3] <- b[3] + c[3]
a[4] <- b[4] + c[4]
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are not aliased in memory, that is, the memory blocks storing vectors `a`, `b` and `c` do not overlap. This is an ideal case, as no memory aliasing implies no data dependency.

Apart from "data dependency", there is also "control dependency", that is, dealing with "if ... else ..." in "vectorization". However, for time and space reason I will not elaborate on this issue.

---

#### back to the example in the question

Now it is time to investigate the loop in the question.

```
set.seed(0)
x <- round(runif(10), 2)
sig <- sample.int(10)
# [1]  1  2  9  5  3  4  8  6  7 10
for (i in seq_along(sig)) x[i] <- x[sig[i]]
```

Unrolling the loop gives

```
x[1]  <- x[1]
x[2]  <- x[2]
x[3]  <- x[9]   ## 3rd instruction
x[4]  <- x[5]
x[5]  <- x[3]   ## 5th instruction
x[6]  <- x[4]
x[7]  <- x[8]
x[8]  <- x[6]
x[9]  <- x[7]
x[10] <- x[10]
```

There is "read-after-write" data dependency between the 3rd and the 5th instruction, so the loop can not be "vectorized" (see **Remark 1**).

Well then, what does `x[] <- x[sig]` do? Let's first explicitly write out the temporary vector:

```
tmp <- x[sig]
x[] <- tmp
```

Since `"["` is called twice, there are actually two C-level loops behind this "vectorized" code:

```
tmp[1]  <- x[1]
tmp[2]  <- x[2]
tmp[3]  <- x[9]
tmp[4]  <- x[5]
tmp[5]  <- x[3]
tmp[6]  <- x[4]
tmp[7]  <- x[8]
tmp[8]  <- x[6]
tmp[9]  <- x[7]
tmp[10] <- x[10]

x[1]  <- tmp[1]
x[2]  <- tmp[2]
x[3]  <- tmp[3]
x[4]  <- tmp[4]
x[5]  <- tmp[5]
x[6]  <- tmp[6]
x[7]  <- tmp[7]
x[8]  <- tmp[8]
x[9]  <- tmp[9]
x[10] <- tmp[10]
```

So `x[] <- x[sig]` is equivalent to

```
for (i in 1:10) tmp[i] <- x[sig[i]]
for (i in 1:10) x[i] <- tmp[i]
rm(tmp); gc()
```

which is not at all the original loop given in the question.

---

#### Remark 1

If implementing the loop in Rcpp is seen as a "vectorization" then let it be. But there is no chance to further "vectorize" the C / C++ loop with "SIMD".

---

#### Remark 2

This Q & A is motivated by [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52594597/4891738). OP originally presented a loop

```
for (i in 1:num) {
  for (j in 1:num) {
    mat[i, j] <- mat[i, mat[j, "rm"]]
  }
}
```

It is tempting to "vectorize" it as

```
mat[1:num, 1:num] <- mat[1:num, mat[1:num, "rm"]]
```

but it is potentially wrong. Later OP changed the loop to

```
for (i in 1:num) {
  for (j in 1:num) {
    mat[i, j] <- mat[i, 1 + num + mat[j, "rm"]]
  }
}
```

which eliminates the memory aliasing issue, because the columns to be replaced are the first `num` columns, while the columns to be looked up are after the first `num` columns.

---

#### Remark 3

I got some comments regarding whether the loop in the question is making "in-place" modification of `x`. Yes, it is. We can use `tracemem`:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- round(runif(10), 2)
sig <- sample.int(10)
tracemem(x)
#[1] "<0x28f7340>"
for (i in seq_along(sig)) x[i] <- x[sig[i]]
tracemem(x)
#[1] "<0x28f7340>"
```

My R session has allocated a memory block pointed by address `<0x28f7340>` for `x` and you may see a different value when you run the code. However, the output of `tracemem` will not change after the loop, which means that no copy of `x` is made. So the loop is indeed doing "in-place" modification without using extra memory.

However, the loop is not doing "in-place" permutation. "In-place" permutation is a more complicated operation. Not only elements of `x` need be swapped along the loop, elements of `sig` also need be swapped (and in the end, `sig` would be `1:10`).

Comment: I agree sommewhat with the first paragraph. it is the assignment to x from x sequentially versus "en bloc" that causes the discrepancy, but there is never over-writing of a "memory block". R does not make assignments "in place". Rather it makes a temporary copy of the original and renames it. And I would also not say it is a danger of "vectorization" since you were not really using what is called vectorization when using a `for`-loop. I would have considered the vectorized result correct and the `for`-loop method as incorrect.

Comment: I will be very surprised if this turns out to be the case. I'll try to track down more authoritative documentation.

Comment: I think you are not understanding how `tracemem` works. Try `a <- 1:10;
 tracemem(a);
 a <- a[10:1];
 tracemem(a)`. The location of `a` changes.

Comment: @李哲源 @42- Also keep in mind that R3.4.0 introduced just-in-time compilation for top-level loops. I'd guess the end result might depend on how sophisticated that compiler is. (`compiler::enableJIT(0)` can turn it off for testing)

Comment: The edit has erased the text I was disagreeing with. It was 'There is actually a trap here: address aliasing. The loop reads x and writes to x. The memory block it reads overlaps the memory block it writes to. Such self-reference introduces loop dependency and is a hazard for "vectorization".'

Comment: Suggested improvement: 1> when explaining "SIMD" analogy of R-sense "vectorization", I should use *"vector registers in CPU -> temporary vectors in RAM"*. Yes, "R" vectorization a RAM-RAM version not a register-register version; 2> In "Remark 2", I should further state that `"rm"` column of `mat` are positive integers.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler explanation. With your loop, you are overwriting one element of `x` at every step, replacing its former value by one of the other elements of `x`. So you get what you asked for. Essentially, it is a complicated form of sampling with replacement (`sample(x, replace=TRUE)`) -- whether you need such a complication, depends on what you want to achieve.

With your vectorized code, you are just asking for a certain permutation of `x` (without replacement), and that is what you get. The vectorized code is *not* doing the same thing as your loop. If you want to achieve the same result with a loop, you would first need to make a copy of `x`:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- x2 <- round(runif(10), 2)
# [1] 0.90 0.27 0.37 0.57 0.91 0.20 0.90 0.94 0.66 0.63
sig <- sample.int(10)
# [1]  1  2  9  5  3  4  8  6  7 10
for (i in seq_along(sig)) x2[i] <- x[sig[i]]
identical(x2, x[sig])
#TRUE
```

No danger of aliasing here: `x` and `x2` refer initially to the same memory location but his will change as soon as you change the first element of  `x2`.

Comment: The for-loop error/confusion is _not_ sampling with replacement.

Comment: @42 sure, what I meant was that what you get could just as well be the result of sampling with replacement. You're right that some values get moved more than once but then again, in sampling with replacement, some values can get selected more than once too.

Comment: The probability distribution of the for-loop process is different than the probability distribution resulting from sampling with replacement.

Comment: you're right, the `for` version does more replacement, so less of the original items will remain in the result. I did a small simulation too, sampling from `1:10`, and the mean number of unique items remaining in the result was 5.5 with the `for` version, and 6.5 with `sample(..., replace=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with memory block aliasing (a term I have never encountered before). Take a particular permutation example and walk through the assignments that would occur regardless of the implementation at the C or assembly (or whatever) language level; It intrinsic to how any sequential for-loop would behave versus how any "true" permutation (what one gets with `x[sig]`) would occur:

```
sample(10)
 [1]  3  7  1  5  6  9 10  8  4  2

value at 1 goes to 3, and now there are two of those values
value at 2 goes to 7, and now there are two of those values
value at 3 (which was at 1) now goes back to 1 but the values remain unchanged
```

... can continue but this illustrates how this will usually not be a "true" permutation and very uncommonly would result in a complete redistribution of values. I'm guessing that only a completely ordered permutation (of which I think there is only one, i.e. `10:1`) could result in a new set of x's that were unique.

```
replicate( 100, {x <- round(runif(10), 2); 
                  sig <- sample.int(10); 
                  for (i in seq_along(sig)){ x[i] <- x[sig[i]]}; 
                  sum(duplicated(x)) } )
 #[1] 4 4 4 5 5 5 4 5 6 5 5 5 4 5 5 6 3 4 2 5 4 4 4 4 3 5 3 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 5 5 5 4
 #[43] 5 3 4 6 6 6 3 4 5 3 5 4 6 4 5 5 6 4 4 4 5 3 4 3 4 4 3 6 4 7 6 5 6 6 5 4 7 5 6 3 6 4
 #[85] 8 4 5 5 4 5 5 5 4 5 5 4 4 5 4 5
```

I started wondering what the distribution of duplication counts might be in a large series. Looks pretty symmetric:

```
table( replicate( 1000000, {x <- round(runif(10), 5); 
                            sig <- sample.int(10); 
               for (i in seq_along(sig)){ x[i] <- x[sig[i]]}; 
                            sum(duplicated(x)) } ) )

     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8 
     1    269  13113 126104 360416 360827 125707  13269    294
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting to see that although R "vectorization" is different from "SIMD" (as OP nicely explained), the same logic applies when determining whether a loop is "vectorizable". Here is a demo using examples in OP's self-answer (with a little modification).

Example 1 with "write-after-read" dependency is "vectorizable".

```
// "ex1.c"
#include <stdlib.h>
void ex1 (size_t n, size_t *x) {
  for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) x[i - 1] = x[i] + 1;
}

gcc -O2 -c -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec ex1.c
#ex1.c:3:3: note: loop vectorized
```

Example 2 with "read-after-write" dependency is **not** "vectorizable".

```
// "ex2.c"
#include <stdlib.h>
void ex2 (size_t n, size_t *x) {
  for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) x[i] = x[i - 1] + 1;
}

gcc -O2 -c -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-missed ex2.c
#ex2.c:3:3: note: not vectorized, possible dependence between data-refs
#ex2.c:3:3: note: bad data dependence
```

Use C99 `restrict` keyword to hint compiler of no memory block aliasing between three arrays.

```
// "ex3.c"
#include <stdlib.h>
void ex3 (size_t n, size_t * restrict a, size_t * restrict b, size_t * restrict c) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
}

gcc -O2 -c -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec ex3.c
#ex3.c:3:3: note: loop vectorized
```